# What is the difference between MySQL error 1194 and error 145

Tags: mysql

As you see, both the MySQL errors 1194 and 145 display the same message:

> ERROR 1194 (HY000): Table 'tablename' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
>
> ERROR 145 (HY000): Table './dbname/tablename' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

On a certain SELECT query I got error 1194, then did `check table tablename;` (which confirmed the corruption); after that, on a `SELECT`, got error 145.

`REPAIR TABLE` helped, still the question is: what is the difference between these errors? Does the 1st one mean the corruption came as the result of that SELECT I tried to perform?

Comment: I think the only way to see the difference is by looking in the MySQL source code.

Comment: I think 145 is used when the table is shown as a pathname, 1194 is when it's just a table name. But I don't know what would cause this difference.

Comment: Interesting. 1194 is documented. However, when you check the global error reference (global error messages have a number<1000), then the highest number is 91 (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/global-error-reference.html). Any mention of error 145 in the official mysql doc is in the backup / recovery section.